# Strange errors iterating empty LINQ to EF result sets

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

At the moment I call any method on a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<T>` that is empty, I get type conversion, null, and `DateTime`overflow errors. The result set is drawn from SqlCe, and I have never seen this with any full version of SQL Server. Is there any way I can avoid iterating it if it's empty, but to see if it's empty, I have to call at least `Any()`, and even that triggers the error.

**NEW:**

This is the code:

```
    Dim points As New List(Of ChartLinePoint)

    ' ***** Fix starts here *****
    Dim carryOn = monitorContext.DataRecords.Any()
    If Not carryOn Then
        Return points
    End If
    ' ***** Fix ends here *****

    recs = monitorContext.DataRecords. _
    OrderBy(Function(dr) dr.INDEX).ThenBy(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP). _
    Where(Function(i) i.INDEX > 2 And i.INDEX < 8). _
    Where(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP >= startTime). _
    Where(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP < endTime). _
    Where(Function(dr) instrumentIds.Contains(dr.DeviceId))

    For Each rec As DataRecord In recs.ToList()
        Dim point = New ChartLinePoint
        point.Id = rec.Id
        point.Index = rec.INDEX
        point.AdHoc = adHoc
        point.DeviceId = rec.DeviceId
        point.TimeStamp = rec.TIMESTAMP
        point.P = rec.P
        point.E = rec.E
        point.V = rec.V
        point.I = rec.I
        points.Add(point)
    Next
    Return points
```

It seems one is allowed to iterate the `DbQuery` before any criteria are added, but not after.

Comment: Could you possibly share a little code?

Comment: Indeed, I have worked around the problem, and added source showing how. Note the emphasised bits.